# Is it possible to give animation to GridView?

Tags: android, animation, gridview

I am developing an app where I'm using GridView to display Images uploaded by user.Now I want to give some sort of animation to this entire Grid on some event.Like sliding it from bottom to top or hiding it from top to bottom.How can I acheive this?

Thanks for any possible help in advance

Answer (score 4):

```
AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
            Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
            animation.setDuration(50);
            set.addAnimation(animation);
            animation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                    0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
            animation.setDuration(100);
            set.addAnimation(animation);
            LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(
                    set, 0.5f);
            gridview.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
```

Comment: Little description would have been helpful

Comment: Thank you!, is it possible to animate on notifyDataSetChanged() ?